# I want to retrieve data from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query_importer1 = "SELECT * FROM items where item_id ='".$row1["item_id"]."'limit 5 ";

$result_importer1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query_importer1);

for ($i=0; $i<=mysqli_num_rows($result_importer1); $i++)

{ 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_importer1);
    echo ''.$row['item_name'].'<br>';
}
```

i want all item name but its printing only one

Comment: i want all item name but its printing only one

Comment: OK, you want to retrieve data, We see your code. But what's the question?

Comment: check how many entries in your database. I mean the result of this
$query_importer1 = "SELECT * FROM items where item_id ='".$row1["item_id"]."'limit 5 ";

Comment: You forgot `while`

Comment: `'limit 5` Missing a space there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need to execute for loop on records, You can get all records using while loop, Plz refer below code

```
$query_importer1 = "SELECT * FROM items where item_id ='".$row1["item_id"]."' limit 5 ";

$result_importer1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query_importer1);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_importer1)){
    echo $row['item_name'];
}
```

Comment: how do i get last inserted values from mysql in array